# Align right with indentation

Tags: css

I have text which has to be right aligned, and when this text takes up more than one line and wraps around, that new line has to be distinguishable from the line after, so I'm trying to get it to indent on the right side, but I can't find a solution which works.

I've tried what was suggested on [the htmlhelp forums thread #8327] and [codingforums thread #58451] as well as a combination of the two to no avail (Can't post links. Sorry.). Is there any other way of accomplishing this?

My attempts:

```
div.poem li:after
{
 content: " ";
 display: inline-block;
 width: 10px; 
}
```

Does something, but I don't want it to indent if the text only takes up one line.

```
div.poem li::first-line::after
{
 content: "asdf";
}
```

Does nothing

```
div.poem li:first-line
{
 color: red;
 margin-right: 200px;
 padding-right: 200px;
}
```

Text on the first line turns red (so that I know what's going on) but the margin and padding doesn't do anything.

HTML:

```
<div class='poem'>
    <ul class='poem'>
        <li>Here's one line of the poem</li>
        <li>This is the second line of the same stanza, which is long and will wrap around</li>
        <li>Part of the line above is now on line 3, and looks like it's supposed to be a line of its own.</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the poem text in that <li> tag only with page breaks? or do you have each new line in a new <li> tag?

Comment: In your last example, try a display:block; or display:inline-block; you can than apply margins

Comment: Tried with inline-block and block, with no change to the results.
Each line of the poem is in a <li>.

Comment: See my answer below: use css p {direction:rtl;padding-right:100px;text-indent:-100px;}

Comment: I can think of a way to do it using Javascript, would that be alright?

Comment: Is it mandatory to have each line in a <li>, or if the verse is the same you just can <br /> and end the </li> on the second line? Something like  <li>first line of the poem</li> <li>second line which is damn so <br /> long to go on the other line</li><li>and this is the real 3rd verse</li>. This way the bullet (or whatever) will clearly mark that line being a verse

Comment: With your updated questions: You only want the 2nd <li> to wrap? Or do you want all of them to wrap if the text is long enough? Or do you want all the <li>'s after the first to be indented more?

Comment: Just updated my answer below according you showing an <li> structure where the 3rd <li> needs to be indented.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here you go:

```
p {direction:rtl;padding-right:100px;text-indent:-100px;}
```

This sets the css direction to be from right to left.
Then add right padding to indent the whole thing from the right
Then use a negative indent that causes the first line to be "outdented"

Your content and text-flow is still left to right (i.e. breaks on the right), it just interprets the css (e.g. paragraph text-indent) on the other side.

Here's my code:

http://jsbin.com/ukese5/7

Comment: The text is to be right-aligned, so you wouldn't use direction: rtl, you'd just use text-align: right.

Comment: Thanks. This indents as it should, but it moves the last punctuation mark to the beginning of the line.
Without the change in direction, it doesn't indent (or indents on the left, but the result's the same).

Comment: rtl will cause it to be right aligned. The point of using rtl is to apply the other css attributes that would normally apply on the left, to be applied on the right. What you want is paragraph out-denting but on the right side. Using a negative text-indent and padding achieves this, but on the left, so using rtl performs it on the right. Using text-align only justfies on the right, it does not apply the text-indent on the right. rtl satisfies both requirements. see the jsbin example.

Comment: Ok, I got around the punctuation issue by adding an invisible character after each line:

    div.poem li:after { content: "a"; font-size: 0px;}

Comment: Based on the updated HTML markup it seems you only want the 3rd line indented. If you are controlling  lines by having each one in a new <li> tag then you can use CSS to control that with CSS3 selectors. Check my updated answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I found an examples [here](http://www.codingforums.com/showpost.php?s=24650a34688915266125f9152001ff01&p=390423&postcount=3), where it is explained how to create a left indented list of links. It only seems to work on left aligned text though since the method includes using `text-indent`. In your case (left-aligned) it would look like this:

```
div.poem li  { padding-left: 2em; text-indent: -1em;  }
div.poem     { text-align: right; }
```

I tried right aligning it but that didn't work. Is the text being read from Right-To-Left? In that case this should work:

```
div.poem li  { padding-left: 2em; text-indent: -1em;  }
div.poem     { direction: rtl; }
```

I assumed his HTML markup:

```
  <div class="poem">
    <ul>
      <li>This text goes on for sometime.This text goes on for sometime.This text goes on for sometime.This text goes on for sometime.This text goes on for sometime.This text goes on for sometime.This text goes on for sometime.This text goes on for sometime.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

---

Updated answer based on the your `<li>` structure:

```
div.poem li:nth-child(3)  { padding-right: 2em;  }
div.poem { text-align: right; }
```

Please note that these are CSS3 selectors and that much older browsers don't support `:nth-child()`. Since the reading of the english text still works you can use that solution also. To learn more you visit the [specification page](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo).

Another thought: If you create these `<li>` using code, you can add a class on the `<li>` that you want indented. And then use more browser friendly CSS to indent it.

The only thing left is to sort out if you want the bullet points or not. Those can be taken away with:

```
div.poem ul  { list-style: none; }
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, I tried that one too. It's English text, so it's read left to right.

Comment: Well this would still work though since you can still read it like english. Try it out :) !