# text-indent does not work while text-align: right

Tags: css

Today I have had a problem with hiding text with `text-indent: -9999px` rule. I realized that it was caused by some parent element which has had `text-align: right`. [Example on jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/sNbfv/)  Setting `text-indent` to positive value of `9999px` did not work as well.

I have managed to hide text by setting it's `text-align` to the `left`, but I do not understand why such problem occurred.

Could someone explain why `text-indenting` does not work while `text-align` is set to the `right`?

Fiddle with ids:
http://jsfiddle.net/sNbfv/2/

Comment: Your fiddle works perfectly for me. What browser?

Comment: @Truth: Note, that `third` div has class `intended` and it IS NOT visible. `second` div has also class `intended` but it IS visible.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It seems that maintaining the alignment is more important to the browser, so the right edge of the text is kept to the right side, no matter what.

The document is set to the `ltr` direction, so the indent is applied to the left of the line, but since you've said you want it to align to the right, the browser disregards the indent entirely. I have no explanation as to why this happens, other than early browsers setting a precedence of justification importance. There is nothing in the CSS spec as far as `text-align` explicitly ignoring `text-indent`.

> The box is indented with respect to the left (or right, for
>   right-to-left layout) edge of the line box. User agents must render
>   this indentation as blank space.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#propdef-text-indent

If we update the fiddle to have an `rtl` direction, the indent indeed affects the right side of the text. I've added a border to show that the overflow is happening.

http://jsfiddle.net/sNbfv/3/

```
.rtl{direction:rtl;}
.parent { text-align: right; border:1px solid blue}
.indented { text-indent: -9999px; }

<div class="rtl">
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="indented">
            Lorem ipsum ipsum!
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="indented">
        Cupcake ipsum!
    </div>
</div>
```

---

The simple solution seems to be aligning that nested indent `to text-align:left`.

http://jsfiddle.net/sNbfv/4/

```
.parent { text-align: right; border:1px solid blue}
.indented { text-indent: -9999px; }
.parent .indented{ text-align:left; }

<div class="parent">
    <div class="indented">
        Lorem ipsum ipsum!
    </div>
</div>

<div class="indented">
    Cupcake ipsum!
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

### [CSS 3 Specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html):

> “This property specifies the indentation of the first line of text in a block container. More precisely, it specifies the indentation of the first box that flows into the block's first line box. The box is indented with respect to the left (or right, for right-to-left layout) edge of the line box. …”
>
> “Note: Since the 'text-indent' property inherits, when specified on a block element, it will affect descendant inline-block elements.”

May be the last quote can explain magic `display: inline-block;` effect.

Also, accordingly to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4844724/1057730) to similar question. `direction: rtl;` force element to respect **css spec**: “box is indented with respect to the left (or right, for right-to-left layout”. I think `text-align: right;` works in similar way.

Comment: indeed setting the element to `direction:rtl` solves the strangeness.

Answer (score 1):

Just change `text-indent:-9999px` to `text-indent:9999px` when combined with `text-align: right`

Answer (score 0):

So... I found something interesting on this.

If you have an element with `text-align:right` and you indent the text left (`text-indent:-9999px`) the text will show.

I guess aligning text one direction and indenting another is rather contradictory. However, changing the `text-indent` to a positive number (`text-indent:9999px`) the indent is respected.

On another note, another (more elegant?) solution is to not indent the text at all but to push it outside the element.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robche/TNdbh/

Comment: Added an `overflow:hidden` to the list as indenting to the right remains in the dom flow... hmm... maybe the second solution I posted is better after all :)

Answer (score 0):

`white-space: nowrap` property solved the issue in my  anchor element.